# How to broadcast a tensor from main process using Accelerate?

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface, accelerate

I want to do some computation in the main process and broadcast the tensor to other processes. Here is a sketch of what my code looks like currently:

```py
from accelerate.utils import broadcast

x = None
if accelerator.is_local_main_process:
    x = <do_some_computation>
    x = broadcast(x)  # I have even tried moving this line out of the if block
print(x.shape)
```

This gives me following error:
`` TypeError: Unsupported types (<class 'NoneType'>) passed to `_gpu_broadcast_one` . Only nested list/tuple/dicts of objects that are valid for `is_torch_tensor` s hould be passed. ``

Which means that `x` is still `None` and is not really being broadcasted. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`x` cannot be `None`. It has to be a tensor that is the same shape and on the correct device (of the current process). I suspect this is because `broadcast` internally does a `copy_`. For some reason, an empty tensor also does not work. Instead, I just created a tensor with all zeros.

```py
from accelerate.utils import broadcast

x = torch.zeros(*final_shape, device=accelerator.device)
if accelerator.is_local_main_process:
    x = <do_some_computation>
    x = broadcast(x)
print(x.shape)
```